# Internet Explorer faulting application when printing

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer

> **PROBLEM**

Single user cannot print from Internet Explorer 9, application crashes and the following event log is posted to the application log:

### [image: Event log error]

> **WORKAROUND**

Using another browser, such as Firefox or Chrome, allows the user to print fine.

> **STEPS/TROUBLESHOOTING I'VE TRIED**

- Run IE with no add-ons (both as user and Run As Administrator) -- NO FIX
- Disable DEP within Internet Explorer itself -- NO FIX
- Disable DEP completely on PC (and reboot) -- NO FIX
- Disable IE Add-Ins manually -- NO FIX
- Uninstall any Windows updates in the last week -- NO FIX
- Install IE 10 -- NO FIX (in fact crashes upon open everytime until I removed it again)
- In IE setings, Advanced, changed Accelerated Graphics to use software rendering -- NO FIX
- Reset IE settings per MS KB Article [#923737](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923737) -- NO FIX
- Ran SFC /scannow (found no issues) -- NO FIX

---

I'm out of ideas.  I definitely don't want to have to deal with re-imaging the user's PC just to fix printing in IE.

Any other suggestions before I open a ticket with Microsoft support for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after scouring various KB articles (shown in the OP), and trying Gregg's and Longneck's solutions, I was still stuck.

In the end, we ended up uninstalling IE9 completely: [How do I install or uninstall IE9](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-install-or-uninstall-internet-explorer-9)

Once the PC reverted back to IE8, the user could print again.

While not ideal, it ends up fixing the issue until a completely wipe/re-image can be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

Run antispyware like malware bytes.  Reinstall print drivers.  Run hijack this and look for weird BHO or anything that looks like malware.

Comment: Print drivers - it happens with all printers installed (all 8 printers, different manufacturers).  I'll try MalwareBytes and HijackThis and report back.

Comment: Sorry, nothing found and reinstalled printer drivers, still no go.  Next up will be to remove A/V software completely and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen to me if the Low folder in %TEMP% was deleted. Try using the Fix-It from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973479 or:

1. Create a folder in %temp% called Low
2. Run this command to set the low integrity flag for the Low folder: `ICACLS "%Temp%\Low" /setintegritylevel (OI)(CI)low`

Comment: No love there...tried it and didn't help.